# Enable COM ports

Tags: tty, serial-port

I have a costume built computer in which I added two extra COM ports. But I don't know the exact name they were given (e.g. ttyS32). I actually tested all 32 found ports in my computer, and non seem to be any of the added 2.

Connecting and disconnecting devices to see which ports appear and disappear is not an option here, since this is not USB.

How would I enable/configure these ports in ubuntu 12.04.1?